# space between bottom and fixed ul

Tags: css, position, html-lists, margin, fixed

I want my nav bar to be fixed at the bottom of the screen. Now, however, there is some space between the nav bar (ul) and the bottom of the screen. Only margin-bottom: -1% seems to work but I would like to fix it without that or at least understand why it does not work without the negative margin.

Nothing in the body tag is set to limit height size and other stuff on the website reaches all the way down to the bottom.

CSS:

```
        #wrapper{
            position: relative;
            width: 98%;
            left: 1%;
        }
        #navbar{
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 100;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
            /*margin-bottom: -1%;*/
        }
        #navbar ul{
            outline: 1px solid black;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        #navbar ul li{
            outline: 1px solid black;
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

HTML (nav bar sits inside #wrapper, nothing else):

```
 <div id="wrapper">
        <nav id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>Ändra inställningar</li>
                <li>+ Nytt pass</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
...other stuff...
</div>
```

Comment: Have you removed the padding from the body? Also why are you translating the Y-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you should set the height for `#navbar` it's fix trouble

```
#navbar{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    /*margin-bottom: -1%;*/
    height:22px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c31y7kL0/

Comment: @Paulie_D. Combining your solutions did the trick: setting the height and removing the translateY. I wonder, what effect does the setting the height have?